# how to change code from onOpen with menu to onEdit

Tags: api, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to change the following code so that it operates onEdit instead of onOpen and creating a menu.  I just want the information auto populated when ISBN is entered into the "A" column.

```
s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Book Menu')
      .addItem('Get Book Details', 'getBookDetails')
      .addToUi();
}

function getBookDetails(isbn) {

  // Query the book database by ISBN code.
  activeCell = s.getActiveCell();
  value = activeCell.getValue();
  isbn = isbn || value.toString(); // Steve Jobs book 

  // Not a valid ISBN if not 13 or 10 digits long.
  if(isbn.match(/(\d{13}|\d{10})/) == null){
    throw new Error( "Not a valid ISBN: " + isbn);
  }
  var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn:" + isbn;
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var results = JSON.parse(response);
  if (results.totalItems) {

    // There'll be only 1 book per ISBN
    var book = results.items[0];

    var title = (book["volumeInfo"]["title"]);
    var subtitle = (book["volumeInfo"]["subtitle"]) || "*No Subtitle";
    var authors = (book["volumeInfo"]["authors"]);
    var printType = (book["volumeInfo"]["printType"]);
    var pageCount = (book["volumeInfo"]["pageCount"]);
    var publisher = (book["volumeInfo"]["publisher"]);
    var publishedDate = (book["volumeInfo"]["publishedDate"]);
    var webReaderLink = (book["accessInfo"]["webReaderLink"]);

    //Logger.log(book);
    results = [[title, subtitle, authors, printType, pageCount, publisher, publishedDate, webReaderLink]];

  }else{
    results = [["-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-"]];
  }
  s.getRange(activeCell.getRow(), activeCell.getColumn() + 1, 1, results[0].length).setValues(results);
}
```

Comment: Do you want to run both function with onEdit or just the one that's current an onOpen function?

Comment: Running the second function could be problematic considering there is a UrlFetch in it since onEdit functions have to complete within 30 seconds. And the onEdit will need to be an installable trigger since permission is required to perform that function.

Comment: Do you need your trigger to be an installable one? Or a simple trigger would work? And could you also explained what do you want to be changed? So you just want your function to be executed exactly when? Just edit the rows beside the iban to make sure the information is updated?